# HMAC with custom HashAlgorithm

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, hmac

There are built in HMAC's (HMACSHA1 - HMACSHA512 ...).
But is it possible to create a HMAC with a custom HashAlgorithm class?

I tried `HMAC.Create("location")` but that just threw a `NullReferenceException`

Could there be a Constructor like `new HMAC(HashAlgorithm)`?

This is the Code for the HashAlgorithm (Fnv1 Hash):

```
public class Fnv1_32 : HashAlgorithm
{
    private const uint prime = 0x01000193;
    private const uint offsetbasis = 0x811C9DC5;
    private uint _Hash;

    public Fnv1_32()
    {
        this.Initialize();
        this.HashSizeValue = 32;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        this._Hash = offsetbasis;
    }

    protected override void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize)
    {
        for (var i = ibStart; i < cbSize; i++)
        {
            this._Hash *= prime;
            this._Hash ^= array[i];
        }
    }

    protected override byte[] HashFinal()
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(this._Hash);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can tell you one thing for certain: HMAC with this hash function is insecure.  It is trivial to create existential forgeries, even if you do fix up the glaring problem of the size bring way too small...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET Framework you can accomplish this via something like

```
public class HMACFnv1_32 : HMAC
{
    private const string Fnv1CryptoConfigId = "Fnv1_32";

    static HMACFnv1_32()
    {
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(Fnv1_32), Fnv1CryptoConfigId);
    }

    public HMACFnv1_32(byte[] key)
    {
        HashName = Fnv1CryptoConfigId;
        HashSizeValue = 32;
        Key = key;
    }
}
```

On .NET Core the HMAC implementation has been removed, all of the builtin HMAC classes call into system cryptography libraries to perform the HMAC calculations.  So you'd need to write HMAC yourself to use a custom digest with .NET Core.

Comment: I cant seem to find any `InitializeKey` method. Does anyone know why? (I'm on .NET 4.6.1)

Comment: EDIT: `InitializeKey` method is internal. So is there an alternative?

Comment: Looks like setting the `Key` property calls InitializeKey.  Updated the code.

Comment: I tried to implement something as suggested to do SHA3-512, however no luck